# Why are nested flexible boxes failing to contain their contents?

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

Good morning,

When I nest an element with `display: -webkit-box` inside another element with `display: -webkit-box` it fails to contain its elements properly as a flexible box. See text behind delete buttons in below image.

[image]

LI HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="reference">
        <div class="number">1.</div>
        Lawson, B. Sharp, R. (2011). <em>Introducing Html5.</em> New Riders Pub
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

LI CSS (aesthetics omitted):

```
li {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-align: center; /* Vertically center elements within LI */
}
.reference {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /* Expand to fill space */
    display: -webkit-box;
}
.number {
    width: 3ex;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.edit {
    /* I have tried setting a width and -webkit-box-flex: 0,
    but this does not solve the problem. */
}
```

It's crucial that .reference stays flexible as the viewport width changes.

The problem can be solved by removing .reference's `display: -webkit-box;`, but this means I can't use the flexible box model on elements within .reference and I need to, to keep item numbers (1., 2., etc) in their own column.

Any help is most appreciated. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` and the likes to achieve what you want instead of `-webkit-box`, you just need some minor markup changes:

```
<li>
    <div class="reference">
        <div class="number">1.</div>
        <div class="title">Lawson, B. Sharp, R. (2011). <em>Introducing Html5.</em> New Riders Pub</div>
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul {
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-row;
}

.number {
    width: 5%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.title {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85%;
}

.edit {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Obviously, you need to adjust the `width` properties, but this should work and have better cross browser support.

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't quite answer my question. I am deploying to iOS Safari only, using PhoneGap, so browser support isn't important. Using percentages will cause inconsistent gaps between the content as cells stretch to fill the window, whereas using `box-flex: 1` enables me to control that. I'll wait a little longer for an answer, otherwise I'll use yours.